# Foundation 5 and Equalizer

Tags: zurb-foundation, equalizer

I'll try to ask this here, because on Foundation forums I got no answer.
I'm making a mixed layout and I want to use Equalizer to make the first column and the second column the same height. The catch is that the second column is another grid layout. Inside that second grid, Equalizer works like a charm, but between the first and second column it does nothing. I've searched here and there are a lot of people with similar problems, but I did not found a solution for mixed layout, even with simple jQuery functions.
Anyone can help?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
  <div class="row" data-equalizer>
    <!-- first column -->
    <div class="large-2 small-2 columns">
        <div class="panel" data-equalizer-watch>
        <!-- here goes an image -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- second column -->
    <div class="large-10 small-10 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        <div class="row" data-equalizer>
            <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
                <p class="panel" data-equalizer-watch>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
                <p class="panel" data-equalizer-watch>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
                <p class="panel" data-equalizer-watch>Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 small-12 columns">
                <p class="panel">Longer text</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" data-equalizer>
            <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
                <p class="panel" data-equalizer-watch>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
                <p class="panel" data-equalizer-watch>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
                <p class="panel" data-equalizer-watch>Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 small-12 columns">
                <p class="panel">Longer text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked on version 5.2.2: you just cannot do this.

I looked at Foundation foundation.equalizer.js file,
this function is simply not suited for equalize an equalizer inside an equalizer.

In 5.2.2 version, at line 30, you can see how it select elements to equalize:

```
vals = equalizer.find('[' + this.attr_name() + '-watch]:visible')
```

There is no dinstinction between dom levels, it catches every `data-equalizer-watch` without looking for any `data-equalizer` inside a `data-equalizer`

Comment: Thank you! I eventually used another approach. But I think Foundation team should look at that. Don't know how difficult would be to implement that, but sounds like a reasonable feature.